# silly integration question i'm banging my head on the desk to figure out

Tags: integration

How does one integrate the following,

$\sqrt{a}\,da = A\,dt$, where $A$ is a constant and $a$ is a function of $t,$

and get this,

$a(t) = A' t^{\frac{2}{3}}$ where $A'$ is just some other constant not equal to $A$ (I assume — sorry, integration skills are atrocious :( ).

Comment: Are you trying to solve for $a(t)$?

Comment: Also, the title should be changed to be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have
\begin{align*}
\int a^{1/2}\,da&=A\int dt\\
\frac{a^{3/2}}{3/2}&=At+C\\
a^{3/2}&=\frac32At+C\\
a&=\left(\frac32At+C\right)^{\!2/3}.
\end{align*}
Note I relabeled $\dfrac{3C}{2}$ as $C$.

Comment: wow.... I completely missed the fact that you can hit the LHS with a power of 2/3 to cancel the 3/2 exponent :'( I'm a mess hahaha thank you! :D

Comment: You're very welcome!